# Move large files to iPad through Lighting cable

Tags: ipad, firewire

Is there a simple / clever method to move large video files from a NAS => Mac => Firewire => iPad?  The goal is speed: preference is to avoid Wifi.   Assume that I would like to transfer a 600MB home video of a wedding.

As I understand it, the choices for transferring files are:

- lightning (fastest)
- wifi
- bluetooth

Comment: Do you specifically need to use Firewire? Because doing this via USB>Lightning would seem to be straightforward: https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/transfer-files-between-ipad-and-your-computer-ipad32dd03cd/ipados

Comment: @user3439894. thanks!  corrected to lightning

Comment: AFAICT **Apple** didn't make a **iPad** with a **Lightning** _connector_ with greater than **512 GB** _storage_, so how are you going to fit a **600 GB** _file_ on an  **iPad** that has a **Lightning** _connector_?

Comment: @user3439894. Correction 600MB.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have iCloud, Dropbox, or Box you can use these services to copy the files to your ipad. You can move the video clip to icloud, for example and move it from icloud to ipad or just use it while its stored in iCloud.